# Error db.sqlite3 locked when deploying Django using option Continuous deployment in Azure App Service

Tags: django, sqlite, azure, deployment

When i'm deploying a Django project (tried two of them) in Azure App Services (Linux), i always get the error SQLite3 database locked: **OperationalError: database is locked**,when trying to log in. Has someone  an idea or workaround to resolve the problem without changing to another database? I changed the default timeout as mentioned by the official django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes, but the problem remain. I want to keep using sqlite database!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use sqlite in an environment like this.

Comment: The problem is with writing to sqlite file, reading from sqlite doesnt produce the error. I don't want to change the database since sqlite is a file and not a server and i only want to use Azure web app service without a connection to cloud database

Answer (score 0):

App Service locks the db.sqlite3 file, preventing both reads and writes. This behavior doesn't affect an external database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#considerations-for-django

https://vscode-eastus.azurewebsites.net/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux

Test App: https://github.com/itsimplified/slick-crud-app

However, you should be able to use the following way to make the WebApp work by moving the SQLite to Azure Storage.

Please follow the below steps in order to achieve this:

## Mount your Azure Storage to the WebApp:

Example:
[image]

Make necessary changes to the path of the DB file in the application:

Example:

[image]

You should also be able to see the DB file in the Storage:

[image]